# How to refer to person-derived and place-derived species names

Tags: nomenclature

Are there words that categorize latin specific epithets by how they're derived? Specifically, I was wondering if there exist adjectives to refer to:

Person-derived species names as in *Nothura darwini* (these could be "eponymic" or "eponymous" perhaps, but that seems grammatically wrong )

Place-derived species names as in *Amolops hongkongensis* (would these be "toponmyous", or maybe "loconymous"?)

Comment: I think generally both could be called latinisations, as the practice with species names is to take the name and try to translate/modify it into an appropriate Latin genitive case.  As far as a word the gets specific enough to reffer to `eponymic latinisations`, no I don't think there is one.  I searched through the OED a few times but I don't think there is one.  Do you have reason to coin the term?  I would be excited if I was proven wrong.

Comment: This isn't a purpose-driven query – just trying to write a sentence and looking for le bon mot. As an update, I did find a few thousand google hits for "eponymous taxa", but also some criticism of that phrase; and nothing similar for place-derived names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *[A Source-Book of Biological Names and Terms](http://books.google.com/books/about/A_source_book_of_biological_names_and_te.html?id=LDXwAAAAMAAJ)* by Jaeger, the appropriate terms are the simple, obvious ones:

**"Geographical"** for place-derived names and

**"Personal"** for person-derived names.

[image]